# How to handle mongoDB failover (re-election), with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, failover

I am trying to make my node js app handle MongoDB connection during the election. I am using a mongoose driver.

I am testing this scenario by, calling an API in a loop (every 250ms), which tries to read from DB and then update a particular document. Then I start the failover in Mongo DB (using test failover option). As the election happens, 2 or 3 of my API calls returns an error (~ for 1sec).

Errors:
`MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false`
OR
`{"stack":"MongoNetworkError: connection 2 to <host>.mongodb.net:27017 closed`

Then mongoose will try to connect to the new primary, and then the API starts to return success.

But before mongoose reconnects with the primary, my API calls are returning errors. How to handle this?

Comment: Versions of all software involved including the driver?

Comment: @D.SM mongo 4.0 and mongoose 5.2.9

Comment: Driver version?

Comment: @D.SM driver: 3.1.3

Comment: Most recent release is 3.5.7.

Comment: @D.SMi updated driver, but still, my apis's are failing for aprox 1 sec

Comment: Using unified topology? http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/reference/unified-topology/

Comment: @D.SM It worked. Thanks a lot. it was that simple